# Error: Request failed with status code 500 Laravel/Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, internal-server-error

This is the full error message in the console :

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/formSubmit 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:279
xhrAdapter @ app.js:118
dispatchRequest @ app.js:726
Promise.then (async)
request @ app.js:528
Axios.<computed> @ app.js:553
wrap @ app.js:1071
formSubmit @ app.js:1896
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:25465
invoker @ app.js:25790
original._wrapper @ app.js:31143
```

I'm trying to get data from a VueJs form and insert them into a MySql database through a laravel controller

My VueJs submit method:

```
        methods: {
            formSubmit(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let currentObj = this;
                axios.post('/formSubmit', {
                    first: this.first,
                    last: this.last,
                    phone: this.phone,
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    currentObj.output = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    currentObj.output = error;
                });
            }
```

My controller:

```
class StudentsController extends Controller
{
    public function formSubmit(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'first' => 'required|string',
            'last' => 'required|string',
            'phone' => 'required',
        ]);

        $s = new Student();
        $s->first = $validatedData->first;
        $s->last = $validatedData->last;
        $s->phone = $validatedData->phone;
        $s->save();

        return response()->json($validatedData);
    }
}
```

It's just a demo project so if there's other ways to submit without getting this error that'll work too.

Thanks

Comment: Open your browser dev tools and find the error in the network tab preview

Comment: It says "Trying to get property 'first' of non-object"

Comment: Looks like my database 'first' field was actually named 'first_name' so i was trying to assign $validatedData->first; to something that doesnt exist. Big thank you Caddy DZ that actually helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

500 server error means the problem lies in your laravel controller.
So check every field name of the table. check if there any column name **first** in your table. if it exists check what are you getting from your front-end? check are you getting valid data so at the beginning of the controller check by it.

```
return $request->first
```

if it's also right then try saving data directly from the request

```
$this->validate($request,[
            'first' => 'required|string',
            'last' => 'required|string',
            'phone' => 'required',
        ]);

        $s = new Student();
        $s->first = $request->first;
        $s->last = $request->last;
        $s->phone = $request->phone;
        $s->save();

        return response()->json(['result'=>$s]);
```